# What does "& > :not(style)" do in Material UI v5?

Tags: material-ui

This code is in the examples in the Paper component documentation:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';

export default function Variants() {
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: 'flex',
        '& > :not(style)': {
          m: 1,
          width: 128,
          height: 128,
        },
      }}
    >
      <Paper variant="outlined" />
      <Paper variant="outlined" square />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

link: https://mui.com/pt/material-ui/react-paper/

I wanted to understand what this sector "& > :not(style)" does.

Comment: After having a look at the `:not selector` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) I would assume that the selector would apply to any child element that is not a `<style/>`.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, @Mentlegen

Comment: Thanks for confirming @DobromirKirov. Curious on why they chose this selector specifically, if you have any idea about it

Answer (score 2):

I think two things are worth clarifying.

Firstly, **:not()** represents elements that do not match a list of selectors, so **'& > :not(style)':** means that it applies to all children elements that have no 'style' attribute. If you add style to the first Paper component, e.g., it will be excluded from this CSS rule.

Another way is to use the * selector to apply to all children elements, like this:  **'& > *':** . Since inline style has the highest precedence, this CSS rule defined in this way still won't apply to the first Paper component if it has its own style attribute.